# Is there any way to integrate flutter application with WordPress CMS?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, dart

I am currently developing a flutter application for an existing website that uses WordPress CMS. I want to integrate my application with WordPress. In this way, I can maintain my application with WordPress. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This may help you: https://medium.com/flutter-community/building-flutter-apps-with-wordpress-backend-part-1-e56414a4a79b

Answer (score 0):

There are few packages for wordpress

If you are using 'woocommerce' you can try
https://pub.dev/packages/wordpress_api

If its a simple blog site you can try
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress
or
https://pub.dev/packages/wordpress_client